# Gremlin-Server takes too much memory and hangs

Tags: garbage-collection, hbase, titan, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I'm using gremlin-server (v3.02), with titan-hbase. I'm using the default configuration settings.The server is 8GB memory and 4-cores.

After few hours of work, the server stops responding to queries requests..
It must be said that the requests intensity on the server is NOT high, pretty much low-medium (few requests per hour, maybe less than that).

When cheking gremlin's last server log messages, I see it's about Hbase session timeout, and retries to reconnect the hbase again.
The server CPU and memory are 90-100% at this point.

JDK 1.8.0_45-b14 64bit on Redhat
Using jstat -gc I can all its time is spent in GC, also oldgen is 100%.
I have set "-Xmx 8g" but vitual memory in htop goes up to 12g, with a few tests with xmx I see that virtual memory always gets about "-Xmx + 4g ".
Jmap -histo gives me about 2g of [B (Byte[]) with a gig for CacheRelation and gig for CacheVertex.

After a restarting the gremlin-server, everything is back to normal, and works again.

Any ideas?